# Regex for sub-string capture, with exception that sub-string may or may not be bound by escaped double-quotes

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following strings:

1. "LAW Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998\"LAW TITLE HERE\"."
2. "LEI Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N"

Explanation:

- A. I have some unique identifier in the sub-string ("LAW Nº
     NNNN/YYYY") followed by " - "
- B. Then the DATE identifier, preceded by the word "DATE"
- C. Then a standard continental-format date ("DD/MM/YYYY")
- D. Finally a sub-string containing a document title

***Note:*** The exception is that title sub-strings ***may or may not be contained in double-quotes***.

***Note:*** All titles have the following features; may or may not begin (or contain) alpha and numerical characters as well as punctuation (full stops / periods at end OR contain commas, semi-colons or colons among other punctuation).

***My question:*** How can I, most efficiently, modify the constructed Perl-like regular expression below to handle the exception of the title sub-string not being captured by a double-quote? In short, I want to keep (or retain) the title sub-string from a string regardless of whether it is captured by a double-quote in the two types of strings listed above.

**Current, Perl-like, regular expression:**

> '(?<=DATE \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}(\"|\s+))(.*)$'

**Sample code & Data:**

```
s1<- "LAW Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998\"LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N\"."

s2<-"LAW Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N"

p<-'(?<=DATE \\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}(\"|\\S))(.*)$'

m1<-regexpr(p, s1,perl=T)

m2<-regexpr(p, s2,perl=T)

t1<-regmatches(s1, m1)

t2<-regmatches(s2, m2)

print(t1)

print(t2)
```

**Returns:**

1. > "LAW Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998\"LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN
   >   4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N\"."
2. > "AW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N"

**Current implementation problems, fixes needed:**

1. String 1 has a final '\"' which is an escaped double-quote that
   needs to be excluded from final output.
2. Current regular expression construction excludes first
   non-whitespace character detected.

***Desired output (same output from both sub-strings):***

> 1. "LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N."
> 2. "LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N."

***R Session-Info (base R, no additional packages):***

> R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

Comment: Why not get this value and after that remove the leading/trailing double quotes?

Comment: Question is: How can I, most efficiently, modify the constructed Perl-like regular expression below to handle the exception of the title sub-string not being captured by a double-quote?

If it simply cannot be done, then it cannot be done. However, I am not that familiar with regular expressions and I want to find out if I may be able to capture the sub-strings I need without manipulating the text first.

Comment: PCRE can handle this through a branch reset. However, I am not sure base R can access capture groups with PCRE regex. E.g., `regexec` does not accept `perl=TRUE`... Ah, just thought about `(g)sub`, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach with PCRE here is using a [**branch reset** group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), `(?|...|...)` and use a capturing group in each branch to only get the results into Group 1.

However, the `regexec` function that helps extracting captured group values in R does not accept a `perl=TRUE` argument, nor can we use the branch reset with ICU regex flavor in *stringr* `str_match` / `str_match_all`.

The most convenient way to use a branch reset here is via `sub`:

```
> p <- "(?s).*DATE \\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}(?|\"(.*)\".*|(.*))|.+"
> x <- c("LAW Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998\"LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N\".","LAW Nº 1234/1998 - DATE 01/01/1998LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N", "Something that does not match")
> sub(p, "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N"
[2] "LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N"
[3] ""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CBE2IF/1) and an [online R demo](http://ideone.com/B7lYS2).

The pattern matches strings with our pattern (that is *captured* into Group 1) first with the first outer branch, or the whole string if there is no pattern we are interested in to completely remove it as a result.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?s)` - enable `.` to match linebreak symbols

  - `.*` - matches any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last
  - `DATE \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}` - `DATE` followed with a space, 2 digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/`, 4 digits
  - `(?|"(.*)".*|(.*))` - branch reset group matching either

    - `"(.*)".*` - `"`, any 0+ chars as many as possible (Group 1), `"`
    - `|` - or
    - `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars
- `|` - or

  - `.+` - just match a non-empty string, any 1 or more chars.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient solution I can come up with so far:

***Perl-like regular expression:***

> '(?<=DATE [\d/]{10})(\"|\w)[^\"]+'

***Code:***

```
p<-'(?<=DATE [\\d/]{10})(\"|\\w)[^\"]+'

m1<-gregexpr(p,s1,perl=T)

t1<-gsub('\"', '', regmatches(s1, m1)[[1]])

m2<-gregexpr(p,s2,perl=T)

t2<-gsub('\"', '', regmatches(s2, m2)[[1]])

print(t1)

print(t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in `gsub`:

```
.+?DATE [0-9/]{10}|\"
```

Example:

```
p <- ".+?DATE [0-9/]{10}|\""

gsub(p, "", s1)
# [1] "LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N."

gsub(p, "", s2)
# [1] "LAW TITLE HERE MAY CONTAIN 4|_|D4NUM3R!C OR P_NC7U@7|()N"
```

Here, everything before the title and all double quotes are replaced by empty strings.